# Python QT5 Stylesheet not working on Raspbian

Tags: python, pyqt, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, raspbian

I'm using QT5 and Python to make a GUI. I have this code:

```
self.ui.btn_light_on.setStyleSheet('background-color: green')
```

On Windows 10 and Ubuntu it colors the button green as needed. 
I want to use the application on a Raspberry PI3b+ with Raspbian. 
But on Raspbian the button stays at the default color.

Could you share any tips or workarounds?

Comment: I have used it many times in raspbian and I have not seen problems, if you want help you should provide a [mcve]